# PHP: in_array not returning true

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an issue with in_array not returning true even though duplicates are in an array. After doing some research on this site, I found that a lot of Windows users have issues due to invisible line breaks \r\n etc., but this seems to not be the case because after printing the length of each string, it matches with what I have (no invisible characters). Still, my code seems to be unable to match new values with what's already in the array:

```
$XMLName = "file.xml";
$XMLFile = simplexml_load_file($XMLName);

$categories = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($XMLFile as $ReadFile) {
    $cat = $ReadFile->CategoryName;

    $IsInArray = in_array($cat, $categories);

    if($IsInArray == FALSE) {
        $categories[$i] = $cat;
        $i++;
    }
}

foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo $category . "<br />";
}
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is the case?

Comment: Is `$cat` an array? I doubt it.

Comment: I don't think so (limited coding experience here, hehe), but isn't $cat supposed to be a string and then the second argument of in_array the array?

Comment: Oh, my bad you are right. Then disregard the comment.

Comment: @Cheesy22 can you send sample of your xml file?

Comment: Small tip: In php you can append to the end of an array with `$arr[] = $someValue;`. You don't need that counting variable `$i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace line:

`$cat = $ReadFile->CategoryName;`

with this one:

`$cat = trim($ReadFile->CategoryName->__toString());`

and as @Jamil said you should better replace:

`$categories[$i] = $cat;
        $i++;`

with just

`$categories[] = $cat;`

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! Was it the linebreak issue after all?

Comment: I have no idea what it was on your side and with your data :-) first of all I made code to be sure that var $cat is string (not the simpleXMLElement) and then trim - to delete spaces if any exist on edge.